# Contributions "on behalf of an organization" automatically grant permissions -- can that be turned off?

Tags: permissions, contribution-page, relationships

I was asked whether it is possible to turn off the automatic permissions that are granted when someone fills out a contribution form "on behalf of an organization":

[image: On Behalf Of - relationship permissions]

I assumed I could edit the Employer/Employee relationship and uncheck some permissions boxes there, but I don't see anything like that out of the box.